# Разбить массив байтов(Bitarray) на 16 частей

Tags: c#, .net

У меня есть массив битов размером 512 байт который я получаю следующим образом

```
byte[] key = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.Default.GetBytes(textBox1.Text);
BitArray bits_key = new System.Collections.BitArray(key);
```

Также у меня есть зубчатый(массив массивов) массив в который я хочу записать 16 частей массива `bits_key`. Зубчатый массив и выделение памяти под него выглядят следующим образом:

```
BitArray[][] mass_keys = new BitArray[80][];
for (int i = 0; i < mass_keys.Length; i++) mass_keys[i] = new BitArray[32];
```

Помогите пожалуйста решить данную проблему

Comment: _16 частей_ - а размер массиву задаете 80.

Comment: В Массиве из 80 элементов надо заполнить первые 16 элементов, а они берутся путём разбиения массива bits_key на 16 частей по 32  бита